# How to create a dynamic Javascript Variable from a PHP String

Tags: javascript, php, html, dynamic-variables

How can I create a dynamic Javascript variable using a PHP String?

This approach doesn't work. How should I fix it to make it work?

```
<?php 
    $dynamicHTMLElementId = rand();
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var dynamicHTMLElementId = window[<?php echo json_encode($dynamicHTMLElementId); ?>];
</script>
```

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: in your example you don't need php at all, js can generate random numbers

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is almost correct. Of course, for example `window[1029376]` is not a valid object property of `window`.
As long as your PHP output is JavaScript syntax it will work.

If your code has the purpose to select a random element (as unrealistic as that is), use [document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) for IDs or the other getElementBy... functions.

```php
<?php 
    $dynamicHTMLElementId = rand();
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var dynamicHTMLElement = document.getElementById('<?php echo json_encode($dynamicHTMLElementId); ?>');
</script>
```

This may result in (with the ID being random):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var dynamicHTMLElement = document.getElementById('1335407484');
</script>
```

Simply look at the source code of the output and check the browser console for errors.
Be aware that `json_encode` will not output quotes for a number.

Answer (score 1):

Simple PHP function to initilize a PHP associate array as a JSON object in javascript.

```
function echoVariableInJavascript($variablename,$variable)
{
   echo("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
   echo("var ".$variablename."= JSON.parse(atob(\"".base64_encode(json_encode($variable))."\"));");
   echo("</script>");
}

/*Usage*/
$object = ["ok"=>true,"status"=>"Good"];
echoVariableInJavascript("object", $object);
```